# Finding matrix that conjugates $A$ into rational form

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I am trying to find the rational canonical form of the matrix \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ -2 & -2 & 0 & 1 \\ -2 & 0 & -1 & -2 \end{bmatrix}
over $\mathbb{C}$. Sepcifically, I am trying to find a matrix which conjugates $A$ into rational canonical form. Here is what I have tried:

Let $A$ denote this matrix. We will use row and column operations to reduce the matrix
$$xI-A=\begin{bmatrix}
x-1&0&0&0\\
0&x-1&0&0\\
-2&-2&x&1\\
-2&0&-1&x+2
\end{bmatrix}$$
to diagonal form
$\begin{bmatrix}
x-1&0&0&0\\
0&x-1&0&0\\
-2&-2&x&1\\
-2&0&-1&x+2
\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow{R_1 \leftrightarrow R_3;C_1 \leftrightarrow C_4}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-2&x&-2\\
0&x-1&0&0\\
0&0&0&x-1\\
x+2&0&-1&-2
\end{bmatrix} \\ \xrightarrow{-(x+2)R_1+R_4}\begin{bmatrix}
1&-2&x&-2\\
0&x-1&0&0\\
0&0&0&x-1\\
0&2(x+2)&-x(x+2)-1&2x+2
\end{bmatrix} \\ \xrightarrow{2C_1+C_2;-xC_1+C_3;2C_1+C_4}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&x-1&0&0\\
0&0&0&x-1\\
0&2(x+2)&-x(x+2)-1&2x+2
\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow{-C_4+C_2}\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&x-1&0&0\\
0&1-x&0&x-1\\
0&2&-(x+1)^2&2x+2
\end{bmatrix} \\ \xrightarrow{R_2+R_3} \begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&x-1&0&0\\
0&0&0&x-1\\
0&2&-(x+1)^2&2x+2
\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow{-(x+1)C_2+C_4} \begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&x-1&0&-(x-1)(x+1)\\
0&0&0&x-1\\
0&2&-(x+1)^2&0
\end{bmatrix} \\ \xrightarrow{R_3 \leftrightarrow R_4} \begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&x-1&0&-(x-1)(x+1)\\
0&2&-(x+1)^2&0\\
0&0&0&x-1
\end{bmatrix} \xrightarrow{R_2 \leftrightarrow R_3}\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&2&-(x+1)^2&0\\
0&x-1&0&-(x-1)(x+1)\\
0&0&0&x-1
\end{bmatrix} \\ \xrightarrow{\frac{1}{2}C_2}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&-(x+1)^2&0\\
0&\frac{1}{2}(x-1)&0&-(x-1)(x+1)\\
0&0&0&x-1  
\end{bmatrix} \xrightarrow{-\frac{1}{2}(x-1)R_2+R_3} \begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&-(x+1)^2&0\\
0&0&\frac{1}{2}(x-1)(x+1)^2&-(x-1)(x+1)\\
0&0&0&x-1  
\end{bmatrix} \\ \xrightarrow{(x+1)R_4+R_3}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&-(x+1)^2&0\\
0&0&\frac{1}{2}(x-1)(x+1)^2&0\\
0&0&0&x-1  
\end{bmatrix} \xrightarrow{(x+1)^2C_2+C_3} \begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&\frac{1}{2}(x-1)(x+1)^2&0\\
0&0&0&x-1  
\end{bmatrix} \\ \xrightarrow{R_3 \leftrightarrow R_4;C_3 \leftrightarrow C_4}  \begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&x-1&0\\
0&0&0&\frac{1}{2}(x-1)(x+1)^2  
\end{bmatrix} \xrightarrow{2C_4}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&x-1&0\\
0&0&0&(x-1)(x+1)^2  
\end{bmatrix}$ \
The sequence of row operations is given by $$R_1 \leftrightarrow R_3;-(x+2)R_1+R_4 \mapsto R_4;R_2+R_3  \mapsto R_3;R_3 \leftrightarrow R_4;R_2 \leftrightarrow R_3;-\frac{1}{2}(x-1)R_2+R_3 \mapsto R_3;(x+1)R_4+R_3 \mapsto R_3; R_3 \leftrightarrow R_4$$
Let $V$ be a $4$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ with basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}$ and let $T$ be the corresponding linear transformation. We see that $T$ is given by
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
xe_1=&T(e_1)=e_1-2e_3-2e_4\\
xe_2=&T(e_2)=e_2-2e_3\\
xe_3=&T(e_3)=-e_4\\
xe_4=&T(e_4)=e_3-2e_4
\end{split}
\end{equation} Starting with the basis $$[e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4]$$ we obtain
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
[e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4] \rightarrow & [e_3,e_2,e_1,e_4]\\
\rightarrow & [(x+2)e_4+e_3,e_2,e_1,e_4]\\
\rightarrow & [(x+2)e_4+e_3,e_2-e_1,e_1,e_4]\\
\rightarrow &[(x+2)e_4+e_3,e_2-e_1,e_4,e_1]\\
\rightarrow &[(x+2)e_4+e_3,e_4,e_2-e_1,e_1]\\
\rightarrow &[(x+2)e_4+e_3,\frac{1}{2}(x-1)(e_2-e_1)+e_4,e_2-e_1,e_1]\\
\rightarrow &[(x+2)e_4+e_3,\frac{1}{2}(x-1)(e_2-e_1)+e_4,e_2-e_1,-(x+1)(e_2-e_1)+e_1]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
and using the formulas above, we obtain
$$[2e_3,2e_4,e_2-e_1,e_1-2e_4]$$

Would $$P=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&-1&1\\
0&0&1&0\\
2&0&0&0\\
0&2&0&-2
\end{bmatrix}$$

conjugate $A$ into its rational canonical form?I don't think this is right since the first two generators should be zero if I am not mistaken. What am I not doing correctly?